# Using pandas dataframe, how to copy selected fragment data to other locations in the same dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe like below:
[enter image description here][1]

I want to change it as :
[enter image description here][2]
I use the command:

```
outer[outer['_merge'] == "right_only"].iloc[:,0:columnsize-1] = outer[outer['_merge'] == "right_only"].iloc[: , columnsize:columnsize*2-1].copy()
```

It seems not work. How can I do the slice copy in dataframe?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpttc.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mECIm.png

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more difficult than I expected. I can't find an easy way by searching web pages, so I can turn to the tedious mode. The solution is as follows:

```
...
columnsize = outer.shape[1] // 2  
leftonly = outer[outer['_merge'] == "left_only"].copy()
column_numbers = [x + columnsize for x in range(columnsize - 1)]
leftonly.drop(leftonly.columns[column_numbers], axis=1, inplace=True)
column_numbers2 = np.append(column_numbers, [columnsize - 1, columnsize * 2 - 1])
rightonly1 = outer[outer['_merge'] == "right_only"].copy()
rightonly2 = rightonly1.iloc[:, column_numbers2].copy()
rightonly2.columns = leftonly.columns
df_combined = pd.concat([leftonly, rightonly2], axis=0, ignore_index=True
...
```

the result is as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebBiq.png)